# Wordpress query goes to infinite loop

Tags: wordpress

I have only the following code in a Wordpress template file, and though there are only two posts in the database, it goes to infinite loop.

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '‐1',
    'post_type' => 'products',
);

$myProducts = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
while ( $myProducts->have_posts() ) : $myProducts‐>the_post();
    echo 'loop body';
endwhile;

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

If I print the $myProducts variable, I can see the two posts there. Why the infinite loop then?

Comment: Is there any other code in the WordPress template file that isn't included here? Are you positive the infinite loop is occurring where you think it is?

Comment: Yes, this is the only code in my template. I know the infinite loop is in the while condition, because my screen is full of 'loop body'.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$params = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'post_type' => 'product'
);
$wc_query = new WP_Query($params); 
?>
<?php if ($wc_query->have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while ($wc_query->have_posts()) : $wc_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php else:  ?>
<p>
     <?php _e( 'No Products' ); ?>
</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This works fine for me.

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.